# Golang how to create an array of Date tuples (int, time.Month, int)

Tags: go

How can I create an array of Date tuples (int, time.Month, int) using go 1.18?

```
days := [](int, month, int){
    time.Date(2022, time.Month(07), 04, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC).Date(),
}
```

Comment: Go does not have tuples.  Define a struct type for the slice element or use a time.Time as the slice element.

Comment: But doesnt time.Now().Date() return a tuple?

Comment: Ok so you can't make a slice of the returned type?

Comment: `time.Now().Date` return 3 values. The return val is not a `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a type for the slice element:

```
type Date struct{ year, month, day int }
```

Initialize the field directly from year/month/day instead of threading the values through time.Time.

```
days := []Date{{2022, 7, 4}}
```